# Replace part of text in a file using batch

Tags: replace, batch-file

The file 'MyFile.txt' has a line in it and a part of that line I need replaced.

Example:

The line in the file is like this

```
53544THOIN91111160000000
```

I want to replace '111116' from the existing line in 'MyFile.txt', the thing here is '111116' is a variable and would keep changing. Its basically a Date with the format YYMMDD, i want to read the modified date from another file and replace these numbers in 'MyFile.txt'

Here is the code i tried.

```
set b=MyFile.txt

for /f "tokens= 1" %%c in (%b%) do (set line=%%c)

Set OLDDate=%line:~11,6%

SET filename="AnotherFile.txt"
FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf

SET Month=%filedatetime:~0,2%
SET Date=%filedatetime:~3,2%
SET Year=%filedatetime:~8,2%

SET NEWDate=%Year%%Month%%date%

ECHO OLD DATE = %OLDDate%
ECHO NEW DATE = %NEWDate%
```

I need `%OLDDate%` to be replaced by `%NEWDate%` in 'MyFile.txt' in the position ~11,6

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why powershell couldn't do it?

```
    # Example of PowerShell -replace parameter
    clear-Host
    $file = Get-ChildItem "D:\powershell\snippets\g*.txt"
    foreach ($str in $file) 
    {
    $content = Get-Content -path $str
    $content | foreach {$_ -replace "the the", "the"} | Set-Content $str
    }
    write-Host "After replace `n"
    $file
```

In the foreach loop you can replace any string with another.

Date logic can be used as follows:

```
$anotherfile = gi anotherfile.txt
```

Retrieving date info

```
$year = $anotherfile.LastWriteTime.Year
```

Comment: As is said its a variable, can i replace one variable with another ? Haven't tried powershell, this would be run on user's systems and i din't want any dependencies...

Comment: Windows 7 has powershell natively installed. Windows XP would need a management install update to enable you to use Powershell. It's like an advanced commandline.

Comment: This tool would be run on Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2003 Server, XP, Vista and 7...